# How to remove unwanted URLs from Google Web Master Tools

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I've two sites that one is live and one is test. ex: www.mydomain.com and test.mydomain.com (test site is password protected)
However Google Webmaster Tools indexed some of my test site links(Sometimes it indexed it while I'm remove test site password for testing purpose) and It don't allow to remove it.(using removal tool)

Is there any way to inform Web master tools to this URLs are not correct. Now I've put `robot.txt` file as `User-agent: *
Disallow: /`

Any advise please.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution I used in the past :

- Step 1 : verify the subdomain as a separate site.
- Step 2 : remove
  the directives from the robots.txt for this step.
- Step 3 : After
  its' been verified, add the disallow directive back to the robots.txt
- Step 4 : You may now request removal of the subdomain.

More information there : http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ca/2007/04/requesting-removal-of-content-from-our.html